# FQL Get (multiple) Facebook uid's from link

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How do you get a Facebook uid given a profile link e.g.

```
www.facebook.com/zuck -> uid = 4
```

**Note:** I know you can see an individual link from:
graph.facebook.com/zuck

However since I have several profile links I'm using FQL to request of multiple uid's in a single call.

I'm trying something along the lines of:

```
SELECT uid FROM user
WHERE profile_link = https://www.facebook.com/zuck OR
profile_link = https://www.facebook.com/ChrisHughes OR
profile_link = https://www.facebook.com/etc
```

Any ideas - is this possible?

Alternatively is there a way to batch multiple "graph.facebook.com/userName" basic queries in ONE call?

EDIT:

I've tried using straight jquery to query Facebook but I keep getting an error:

> "Only POST is allowed for batch requests"

My Javascript jquery code is as follows:

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com";
var access_token = "theAccessToken&@#*#^#&$#*##$&*@123";
var postData = [{"method":"POST","relative_url":"zuck"},{"method":"POST","relative_url":"ChrisHughes"}];

$.ajax("https://graph.facebook.com/",{
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {"access_token": access_token, "batch": postData},
    dataType: "jsonp"
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
});
```

Seems that I'm POST-ing to facebook "https" but why does that error come up??

Answer (score 0):

Try this graph API query(Extra the username from the profile link first):

http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=zuck,ChrisHughes,etc&fields=id

[image]